# Distance calculation optimisation

Tags: algorithm

I am writing an algorithm that computes the nearest neighbours of points in a 2d plane. Currently I brute force compute every distance via two for loops

```
for(i=0; i<N ;i++){
   for (j=0; j<N; j++{ 
      /* distance computation */
      /* remember smallest distance for all i */
   }
}
```

I already have an `if(i==j) continue;` statement so that we avoid computing the distances between the same points. I am wondering how can I optimise this algorithm further. For instance how can I account for the symmetry of distance(i,j) = distance (j,i)? Are there any other points that I should think about?

Further, could you describe to me another algorithm that would be a better way to perform this calculation? I have looked into binary trees but am quite unsure how they actually could be applied to my problem!

Comment: do you want an algorithm that returns one solution or all solutions ?(there are in general multiple nearest neighbors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can account for symmetry by starting `j` at `i+1`. This will also take care of the `i == j` situation without a special case:

```
for (i = 0 ; i != N ; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1 ; j != N ; j++) {
        dist = ... // Compute the distance
        distance[i][j] = distance[j][i] = dist; // Set in both directions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) as your data structure

This [nice post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27264/how-do-i-optimize-searching-for-the-nearest-point) gives you details on how to proceed